# Dice coefficient for image segmentation evaluation

Tags: python, image-segmentation, dice, coefficients, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to implement dice coefficient, so I could compare segmented image to ground truth image. However, the output of the dice coefficient seems to be incorrect as segmented image is around 80% similar to the ground truth image. The output of dice coefficient is 0.13. Should be around 0.8.

```
def my_dice(img1,img2):
 intersection = np.logical_and(img1, img2)
 union = np.logical_or(img1, img2)
 dice = (2*np.sum(intersection))/(np.sum(union)+np.sum(intersection))
 return dice
```

I thought the results are odd because of non-binary array (range 0-255). So I divided images by 255, which gave me some floats. This didn't help. So I used python astype(np.bool) but that didn't help as well. To be clear, I performed semantic segmentation on image where is one cell, nothing more and I want to compare with its ground truth using dice coefficient. I have used plenty of methods I've found online but none is give me correct number. Like this one before.

```
    """Soft dice loss calculation for arbitrary batch size, number of classes, and number of spatial dimensions.
    Assumes the `channels_last` format.
  
    # Arguments
        y_true: b x X x Y( x Z...) x c One hot encoding of ground truth
        y_pred: b x X x Y( x Z...) x c Network output, must sum to 1 over c channel (such as after softmax) 
        epsilon: Used for numerical stability to avoid divide by zero errors
    """
   
    # skip the batch and class axis for calculating Dice score
    axes = tuple(range(1, len(y_pred.shape)-1)) 
    print(axes)
    numerator = 2. * np.sum(y_pred * y_true, axes)
    print(numerator)
    denominator = np.sum(np.square(y_pred) + np.square(y_true), axes)
    print(denominator)
    
    return np.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon)) # average over classes and batch
```

The results looks more sensible when I use dice loss which in case of second method the return looks like this:

```
return 1-np.mean(numerator / (denominator + epsilon)) # average over classes and batch
```

However, this is not what I apparently need to have. Both of the images are of shape: (224,224,1)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was caused by having one binary image (true, false) and segmented image in range (0-255). I had to binarized the segmented image and then calculate dice coefficient.